# I am trying to get a function to search an array of objects and then return the entire object based on the filter

Tags: arrays, function, object, callback

I am trying to get my function working and I can not for the life of me figure out why it isnt. I am trying to use .filter() to search the array of objects to find the object with the tag ketchup. Then return the whole object it is in to the console log

```
let foodArr = [
{   
      type: 'Chicken',
      rating: 1,
      tags: ['chicken', 'free-range', 'no hormones'],
      price: 10,
      popularity: 80
},
{
    type: 'pizza',
    rating: 5,
    tags: ['pepperoni', 'sauce', 'bread'],
    price: 25,
    popularity: 56
},
{
    type: 'hamburger',
    rating: 3,
    tags: ['bun', 'patty', 'lettuce'],
    price: 8,
    popularity: 99
},
{
    type: 'wings',
    rating: 4,
    tags: ['wing', 'bbq', 'ranch'],
    price: 12,
    popularity: 68
},
{
    type: 'fries',
    rating: 2,
    tags: ['ketchup'],
    price: 4,
    popularity: 100
}
]


const filteredFood = foodArr.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.tags[''] === 'ketchup'
})
console.log(filteredFood)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filteredFood = foodArr.filter(function(value){
    for (let i=0; i<value.tags.length; i++)
    if(value.tags[i] === 'ranch'){
        return value.tags[i]
    }       
    }
) 
console.log(filteredFood)
```